# Is there a way to have the date entry calendar show up in a blank Date Entry field? (Tkcalendar)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I'm using the latest version of Tkcalendar. Whenever the date entry field is blank, the dropdown doesn't pop up. It throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\JEvans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 246, in _on_b1_press
    self.drop_down()
  File "C:\Users\JEvans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 331, in drop_down
    date = self.parse_date(self.get())
  File "C:\Users\JEvans\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 1223, in parse_date
    year = numbers[indexes['Y']]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's how the date entry widget is constructed in the program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from tkcalendar import *
import tkcalendar


window = Tk()

class DateEntry(tkcalendar.DateEntry):
    def _validate_date(self):
        if not self.get():
            return True # IMPORTANT!!! Validation must return True/False otherwise it is turned off by tkinter engine
        
        return super()._validate_date()


def test():
    pass

window.geometry('500x500')

dob = DateEntry(window, date_pattern = 'mm/dd/yyyy', width = 15, background= 'gray61', foreground="white", locale='en_US')
dob.place(x = 125, y =125)
dob.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", test)

dob2 = DateEntry(window, date_pattern = 'mm/dd/yyyy', width = 15, background= 'gray61', foreground="white", locale='en_US')
dob2.place(x =200, y =200)
dob2.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", test)


window.mainloop()
```

Here is what happens when I click the dropdown. Nothing appears and it returns the error message above.

[image: This is what happens when the dropdown is clicked. It just freezes and returns the error message.]

Is there anyway to bypass this error and have the dropdown show without entering a date value?

Extra Clarification: The date entry works perfectly when there is a date in the date entry field. The error only appears when the field is blank.

Comment: we can't see your code, we can't run it , and we can't read in your mind - so we have no idea what is the problem. You have to put all details in question (not in comments). At this moment this question is waste of time and we can only downvote or close it.

Comment: @furas You're right. I added more information. Tell me if you have any suggestion on how to fix the issue.

Comment: @furas Sorry about not being more specific about the issue/not providing the necessary information. I was in a rush when I posted this.

Comment: I have no idea what is the problem. Better create minimal working code with this problem - so we could simply copy and run to test problem.

Comment: @furas I added a better example. You should be able to run it fine in Python.

Comment: @furas I've narrowed it down that the issue is coming from the class DateEntry(tkcalendar.DateEntry) part. This is the only solution I found to allow blank values to stay in the date entry widget. However, it appears to be bugging out the dropdown for some reason.

Comment: if I remove `if not self.get(): return True` then code works for me without error but automatically it puts current date before opening dropdown. It seems it needs this value in Entry to display dates in dropdown. It may need to get source code and rewrite all widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `dropdown` needs value from this `entry` to generate window with calendar.

It seems normally it replaces empty string in `entry` with current date and later `dropdown` gets this current date from `entry`.

Your code stops replacing empty string so it makes problem with rest of code.

Error shows that `parse_date()` makes problem when you have empty string - so it would need to replace this method and also check if text is empty and use some correct date (ie. current date) so `dropdown` will know what to generate in window with calendar.

I checked source code (using path from `tkcalendar.__file__`) and it seems `DateEntry` doesn't have this function but in `__init__` it sets `self.parse_date = self._calendar.parse_date` and it need different method to replace it.

It needs to run original `__init__` and later keep previous `self.paser_date` and assign own function to `self.parse_date`.

Full working code

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
import tkcalendar
import datetime

#print(tkcalendar.__file__) path to source code (skip __init__.py)

# --- classes ---

class DateEntry(tkcalendar.DateEntry):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.old_parse_date = self.parse_date
        
        self.parse_date = self.new_parse_date
        
    def _validate_date(self):
        if not self.get():
            return True
        
        return super()._validate_date()

    def new_parse_date(self, text):
        print(f'parse_date: >{text}<')

        if not text:
            return datetime.datetime.now()   # return some default date

        return self.old_parse_date(text)     # runs original function
    
# --- functions ---

def test(event):
    print('test:', event)

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(window, text='tkcalendar.DateEntry').pack(padx=5, pady=5)

dob1 = tkcalendar.DateEntry(window, date_pattern='mm/dd/yyyy', locale='en_US')
dob1.pack()
dob1.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", test)

tk.Label(window, text='My DateEntry').pack(padx=5, pady=5)

dob2 = DateEntry(window, date_pattern = 'mm/dd/yyyy', locale='en_US')
dob2.pack()
dob2.bind("<<DateEntrySelected>>", test)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I've accepted your answer. Thank you.